# Add MySQL to existing XAMPP installation

Tags: xampp

I installed XAMPP with only Apache and PHP and now I realized I also need MySQL. I downloaded a XAMPP installer and ran it, but it won't install in `C:\xampp` as it already exists.

How can I add MySQL to the existing Apache+PHP installation?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. could you solve it ?

Comment: @Gonzalo I'm sorry, no. I just made a backup of my htdocs folder I and uninstalled and reinstalled XAMPP.

Comment: It is likely that you want to install also PhpMyAdmin

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

1. Re-run the installer and install **with MySQL** into a different folder. (These instructions assume `c:\xampp2`)
2. After the installation finishes, move the mysql directory from the new install into the old install. (I moved `c:\xampp2\mysql` to `c:\xampp\mysql`) You can then delete the second installation folder.
3. Be sure xampp is not running and edit `c:\xampp\xampp-control.ini`, looking for the `[EnableModules]` section. Set `MySQL=1`.
4. Restart xampp. The MySQL buttons should be enabled. Click the **Config** button next to MySQL and edit the `my.ini` file. Do a search and replace, changing all instances of `xampp2` to `xampp`.

Now you can hit start, and MySQL should start up. *Note these instructions assume **c:\xampp** is your desired install location, adjust accordingly.*

Comment: 5- I also used notepad++ to (find in files) then located (c:/xampp/mysql/) after that replaced all "xampp2" to "xampp" then it worked perfectly, many thanks!

Comment: Someone makes a video for this: [Add MySQL to existing XAMPP installation - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iwn0OqadkiE "Add MySQL to existing XAMPP installation - YouTube")